# How to delete a profile on IMesh?

Tags: windows-xp, imesh

How do I delete a profile on I-mesh?

Operating system is Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use iMesh services anymore, just uninstall the application from your PC.

If you want to keep using iMesh (with the same mail, but different profile), but want to delete the profile - I recommend to send email to the iMesh support guys ([iMesh Support](http://wa.imesh.com/support/helpme.php))
and ask them to completely remove your profile.